# im not able to connect exchange anymore with powershell: Connect-ExchangeOnline error

Tags: powershell, office365

Hi anyone an idea how to fix this.
already run as administrator and reinstalled the ExchangeOnline module.

```
Import-Module MSOnline -DisableNameChecking;

Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement;

Connect-MsolService -Credential $LiveCred;

Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -confirm:$false;

$ExchangeSession = Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $LiveCred -UseRPSSession;
```

```
New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following erro
r message :  For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingT
ransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108173,PSSessionOpenFailed
PS G:\Mijn Drive\scripts\office365> TerminatingError(New-ExoPSSession): "Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message :  For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."
PS G:\Mijn Drive\scripts\office365> TerminatingError(): "Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message :  For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."
>> TerminatingError(): "Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message :  For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."
Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message :  For
more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\3.2.0\netFramework\Exchang
eOnlineManagement.psm1:743 char:21
+                     throw $_.Exception;
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingDataStructureExcep
   tion
```

Comment: Can you connect with just `$ExchangeSession = Connect-ExchangeOnline` ? If yes, then see [Deprecation of Remote PowerShell in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps#-userpssession)

Comment: U are totally right, if I remove the parameters: -Credential $LiveCred -UseRPSSession; Then the script shows a manual credential popup.. and then the script works. So why does it not work anymore to give the credential and useprsSESSION parameter? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The older Exchange Online module used Remote PowerShell (RPS) for client to server communication. Unfortunately, RPS is legacy technology that is outdated and can pose security risks. As such, [Microsoft recommend all customers move to the new more secure REST-based v3 PowerShell module](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/deprecation-of-remote-powershell-in-exchange-online-re-enabling/ba-p/3779692), which will improve security but removes the authentication method you’re using.
Take a look at [Get-Help Connect-ExchangeOnline -Full](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps) for current connection options.

You can use `$ExchangeSession = Connect-ExchangeOnline` to perform an interactive logon.

By the way, the MSOnline module is also going end of life shortly and is replaced by the [Microsoft Graph PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph/2.3.0).

Comment: I also believe the same that by updating to more recent EXO Module, we can resolve this. You can find multiple methods over here.
https://rizwanranjha.com/microsoft/exchange-online/connecting-to-remote-server-outlook-office365-com-failed

Answer (score 0):

Rizwan is right. The exchange online V2 (EXO 2) Module will deprecate.
We just need to upgrade to Module V3 wich uses REST cmdlets. All previous V2 cmdlets will still work they say. Only it will run REST in the background on the Microsoft servers. So our code will be the very same. we just need to upgrade the module to V3. AND change the way we connect to the exchange online management server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps

the deprecation info:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/deprecation-of-remote-powershell-in-exchange-online-re-enabling/ba-p/3779692